# Pandas: Excel cells with equation gives '0' in pandas read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter, excel-2016

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

row = 0
col = 0

for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1


worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

workbook.close()

df = pd.read_excel('Expenses01.xlsx')
r_list = df.values.tolist()

for r in r_list:
    print(r)
```

[image: This Is the output of the program]

If I open the excel manually and close it without changing anything it says save all the changes.
If i save it and read it again with pandas it gives the correct output with the sum value.
I can't seem to understand what is wrong. I am using Excel 2016.In the excel The equation Works Fine.

Comment: It appears that the `read_excel` method is only parsing the XML files associated to your workbook - whereas Excel is running the formula and updating the XML data accordingly.

Comment: Strange Thing is if i open the excel after running the script and just save and close it,
then read the excel again with pandas.
it gives the correct output. With total sum value.

Comment: See this question and answer in the XlsxWriter FAQ: [Q. Why do my formulas show a zero result in some, non-Excel applications?](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging through some `pandas` and `xlrd` code, here is my conclusion - gurus feel free to jump in:

#### Brief Excel Background:

Modern versions of Excel (`.xlsx` files) are a series of XML files from/to which Excel reads and writes.

The Excel EXE is responsible for running equations, such as your `SUM` formula.  So when you open your workbook, Excel is calculating the sum and storing the value to its underlying XML files.

However, without opening Excel, this formula **is not being calculated**.

#### Pandas:

To **oversimplify**, the `pd.read_excel()` function is using the `xlrd` library to parse the XML files and return the values as a `DataFrame`.

However, without Excel to run the calculation(s) (ie: your `SUM` function), this value is not being stored to the underlying XML file.  So you are getting 0 returned.

Here is some [further reading](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html), courtesy of @jmcnamara's comment.

#### Possible Resolution:

A possible resolution for you might be to store your data to a CSV file and let Python (`pandas`) take care of your calculations, and data manipulation.  Pandas is very happy reading and writing CSV files.

Alternatively, look into `subprocess` to open/close Excel from inside your Python script.

**pseudo-code example:**

```
import subprocess
# Open Excel and workbook.
subprocess.Popen('start excel.exe /path/to/myExcel.xlsx', shell=True)
# Kill all open Excel instances.  (Use with care!)
subprocess.Popen('taskkill /f /im excel.exe', shell=True)
```

Comment: Thank You. Now i understand the problem.
Any idea how to solve it?
By solving i mean without opening the excel and saving it.
is there any way around?

Comment: Problem is I have an Excel format(with formulas) Thai is why i want to write first then read with pandas. I appreciate your answer. I helped me understand the problem.

Comment: Gotcha.  Perhaps look into `subprocess` - it allows you to run shell commands from a Python script.  Maybe you can use this to open/close Excel at the end of your Python script.  Updated answer to show a pseudo example.